# json4s - how to use multiple FieldSerializer

Tags: scala, json4s

What is the correct syntax to use multiple FieldSerializer? I'm trying to rename 3 fields it only works if I concat one of them with DefaultFormats

```
val currg = FieldSerializer[Currency](renameTo("gameCurr", "gameCurr"), renameFrom("currg", "gameCurr"))
val curre = FieldSerializer[Currency](renameTo("currency", "currency"), renameFrom("curre", "currency"))
val lprice = FieldSerializer[Currency](renameTo("price", "price"), renameFrom("lprice", "price"))

implicit val formats = org.json4s.DefaultFormats + lprice //+ curre + currg
```

If I let only a single FieldSerializer, it works like a charm

```
implicit val formats = org.json4s.DefaultFormats + lprice
```

Answer (score 3):

You can rename multiple fields in a single `FieldSerializer` with `orElse`:

```
val rename_currency_fields = FieldSerializer[Currency](
  renameTo("foo", "bar") orElse renameTo("baz", "qux") 
  renameFrom("bar", "foo") orElse renameFrom("qux", "baz")
)

implicit val formats = org.json4s.DefaultFormats + rename_currency_fields
```